# Android framework for tab

Tags: android-fragments, android-framework

i want to make framework which can use in android tab.as i know,in android tab (honeycomb 3.x) implement fragment activity.my questions are :

1. how to implement fragment activity?
2. is it different or not environment smartphone and tab in android?

need your suggests,links and tutorials.
big thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(detailPage){
               DetailFragment detailFragment = (DetailFragment)
               getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.displayDetail);
               detailFragment.updateURLContent(URL);
              }
              else{
               DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
               detailFragment.setURLContent(URL);
               FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               ft.replace(R.id.displayList, detailFragment, "Detail_Fragment2");
               ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
               ft.addToBackStack(null);
               ft.commit();
              }
```

detailpage is a boolean flag